# Mathematical Statistics, Probability

Tags: statistics

So say you have a distribution which is $\displaystyle \frac{2x}{\theta^2}$ and $\theta = 7$. What is the probability that the 5th smallest observation exceeds $.01$?

Comment: Also, x can be between 0 and theta, else the pdf is 0

Comment: How many observations are there?

Comment: There are 600 observations

Comment: Hmmm. I'm wondering if this problem could be solved as a left-edge extreme value problem?

Answer (score 2):

Find the probability $p$ that an observation is $\le 0.01$. This is a straightforward integral. We get $p=\frac{1}{490000}$, awfully small. It might be worthwhile to check the numbers, to see whether $0.01$ or $7$ really are intended.

Find the probability all observations are $\gt 0.01$. This is $\left(1-\frac{1}{490000}\right)^{600}$.

For all practical purposes, this is the answer. But in case your numbers change, we go on.

Find the probability that $1$ is $\le 0.01$ and the others are bigger.

Find the probability that $2$ are $\le 0.01$ and the others are bigger.

Find the probability that $3$ are $\le 0.01$ and the others are bigger.

Find the probability that $4$ are $\le 0.01$ and the others are bigger.

Add up. But of the $5$ terms, all but the first are quite tiny.

The probabilities can all be calculated using the *binomial distribution*, $n=600$, $p=p$. The probability that exactly $k$ observations are $\le 0.01$ is $\binom{600}{k}p^k(1-p)^{600-k}$.

**Remark:** With other numbers, the Poisson approximation to the binomial might be useful.